# Scroll to top of md-virtual-repeat

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I am trying to add a "scroll to top of page" button inside an md-virtual-repeat-container. I am currently using $anchorScroll. I have set the hash to a table head (I have tried setting the hash inside and outside of the repeat container) and the md-virtual-repeat is set to repeat the tr's. When the button is clicked the table only scrolls up one item and stops, it doesn't scroll all the way to the top. Any ideas?

I think it might be because the browser thinks it only needs to scroll up one td to reach the hash because that is what is shown in the DOM but in reality it needs to scroll more.

Thank you in advance!

```
    <md-virtual-repeat-container flex>
     <table>
      <thead id='scrollHash'>
       <tr><th></th><tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr md-virtual-repeat='data in repeatData'>
        <td></td>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    <md-button class='md-fab' ng-click'$scope.gotoTop()'>Top</md-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `md-top-index` (read more [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeatContainer)).

Try this:

In html:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container md-top-index="topIndex">...</md-virtual-repeat-container>
<md-button class='md-fab' ng-click="gotoTop()">Top</md-button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.gotoTop = function()
{
    $scope.topIndex = 0;
}
```

Code [here](http://codepen.io/DieuNQ/pen/ONExaa?editors=1010).

Hope this help.

Comment: your rock! Thank you, got too caught up in other stuff and spaced md-top-index. Thanks again!